# Cmdlet Get-ADGroupMember only working on domain controller but not on other servers when FSPs are included

Tags: active-directory, powershell, ldap

we have an AD forest with two domains:

- company.com
- test.company.com

We have replaced the domain controllers for test.company.com (OS changed from W2012R2 to W2022, but not as in place upgrade).
Since then I am not able to use Active Directory Web Service (ADWS) properly when a Foreign Security Principal (FSP) is included.

e.g. using `Get-ADGroupmember -Server company.com -Identity Companygroup1 | Select-Object name`

I get this exception:

```
Get-ADGroupmember : An unspecified error has occurred
At line:3 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupmember -Identity Companygroup1  | Select-Object nam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Companygroup1 :ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

If I use the same Cmdlet on the company.com Domain Controllers everything is working, but on a client or on a test.company.com DC I get the mentioned exception.
Before replacing the test.company.com DCs everything worked (= requests with FSPs were working from every computer in both domains). Now it does not work for both domains in my forest.

The group is containing users from two different forests:

- group.com (selective bidirectional trust)
- vienna.com (bidirectional full trust)

The truss relationship does not seem the issue, because I tried it with groups containing only FSPs from one trusted domain, but that had no effect.

Things I have checked:

- The users still exists in the foreign domain
- firewall does not block the requests - network connectivity is fine
- it is not related to my user-account
- my TGT is forwardable
- Logs of the DCs do not contain any specific error (only the "An unspecified error has occurred" event)
- I have restarted ADWS multiple times

Has anyone an idea why this happens? Especially why upgrading the test-subdomain DCs affects the company.com domain?
I am absolutely clueless.

Comment: What is the resulting output when the command is run without piping the output?

Comment: There is no difference in using the Pipeline or not

Comment: See if [Get-ADGroupMember returns error for domain local group to members from remote forests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/get-adgroupmember-error-remote-forest-members) helps

Comment: Unfortunately not. The FSPs are valid and still exist in the trusted domain. I have verified that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, I found the issue.
The domain has turned on Kerberos Constrained Delegation. That is the reason it works from DC (because no delegation necessary in this situation)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview